# How can I find what options I can set with a `helm install` that the chart provides?

Tags: helm

Let's say I want to install an arbitrary helm chart like `mysql-operator/mysql-innodbcluster` how can I find what options I set with `--set`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `show values` to see what options the chart provides,

```
helm show values mysql-operator/mysql-innodbcluster
```

What you'll get is a YAML file, here is a part of the above YAML output,

```yaml
tls:
  useSelfSigned: false
#  caSecretName:
#  serverCertAndPKsecretName:
#  routerCertAndPKsecretName:
```

You an set the option for `useSelfSigned` as `tls.useSelfSigned` like this:

```
helm install mycluster mysql-operator/mysql-innodbcluster --set tls.useSelfSigned=true
```